# Apache mod_rewrite manipulate captured variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to translate the following URL:

```
http://my.domain.net/locations
```

to

```
http://my.domain.net/location_list.php
```

My current rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(locations)$ /$1_list.php
```

But that mean that my file must be named *locations_list.php*. So ideally I would like to remove the *'s'* from my variable $1, is this possible? I'm having problems finding any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `s`:

```
RewriteRule ^(location)$ /$1_list.php
```

or make it optional

```
RewriteRule ^(locations?)$ /$1_list.php
```

or make it so it's not captured

```
RewriteRule ^(location)s$ /$1_list.php
```

Comment: Thank you, the no capturing part was just what I was looking for. I ended up with this rule: 

RewriteRule ^(location|component)s$ /$1_list.php